# Lookup Groovy Beans in App Context

Tags: spring, groovy

I have several Groovy beans defined within my app context file, like so:

```
<lang:groovy id="bean1">
   ...
</lang:groovy>
```

I would like to get a list of all the groovy beans from the **ApplicationContext**, but don't see a clean way to do this.

Is there a straightforward way to get a list of all the Groovy implemented beans?

I am using Spring 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
applicationContext.getBeansForType(Class.forName("groovy.lang.GroovyObject"));
```

See [`ListableBeanFactory`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html) Javadoc.

Comment: What type do I use though? I believe the Groovy beans get wrapped in a proxy object, but I have yet to find the correct type.

Comment: sorry, my initial answer used getBeansOfType and had angle brackets with the type which SO removed :)